# check textbox on NULL

Tags: javascript, html

How to check if input="text" value is not NULL and then move to page?

```
<input TYPE="text" name="textbox2" align="center">
........
function HomeButton()
                {
                    <!--if textbox1 value and textbox2 value not null-->
                        location.href="registration.html";
                }
```

Comment: It'll never be `null`. Do you mean an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that both their values are truthy.

```
var textbox1 = document.getElementsByName('textbox1')[0];
var textbox2 = document.getElementsByName('textbox2')[0];

if(textbox1.value && textbox2.value) {
    location.href = "registration.html";
}
```

---

Of course, you can make things easier by giving them `id`s:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" align="center">
```

and

```
var textbox2 = document.getElementById('textbox2');
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Give the textboxes an `id`

```
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="textbox2" align="center" />

if (document.getElementById('textbox1').value !== null &&
    document.getElementById('textbox2').value !== null) {
                    location.href="registration.html";
}
```

But the value will never be `null`, so you probably want to check for empty string:

```
if (document.getElementById('textbox1').value &&
    document.getElementById('textbox2').value) {
                    location.href="registration.html";
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. Also, the elements don't have `id`s, they have `name`s - you might want to suggest giving them `id`s or something first, just in case.

Comment: @minitech. allready did... **Edit:** Forgot to indent the code so the markup was not shown, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1, assign that input a id for better orientation in code

2, i suggest using jquery, if not you could do it like this:

```
<input TYPE="text" name="textbox2" align="center" id="textbox1">
........
function HomeButton()
                {
                    if (document.getElementById('textbox1').value != "" && document.getElementById('textbox1').value != null) {
                        location.href="registration.html";
                }
```